# дано не отрицательное число, вы должны вернуть цифры этого числа в массиве в обратном порядке

Tags: javascript, массивы

дано не отрицательное число, вы должны вернуть цифры этого числа в массиве в обратном порядке

342587 => [7,8,5,2,4,3]

0 => [0]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: так задание звучит на сайте ctrl-c ctrl-v

Comment: Ну хорошо. А что вы хотите? Алгоритм действий? Готовой решение? Что-то еще?

Comment: готовое решение. я не понимаю как сделать это задание

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Всем привет, вот вам мысль

```js
    let n=342587;
    mas=Array.from(String(n), Number).reverse();
    console.log(mas);
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

```
const firstNum = 0;
const secondNum = 342587;

function getArrayFromNum(num) {
    const arrayFromNum = String(num).split('').reverse();
    return arrayFromNum;
}

console.log(getArrayFromNum(firstNum));
console.log(getArrayFromNum(secondNum));
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).